# How does the draggable crosshair in Process Explorer work?

Tags: c++, .net, sysinternals

There is a feature in Sysinternal's [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) that allows a crosshair to be dragged from the application to a control in any other application you are running and highlights said control.

Does anyone know how this was achieved or if there is a .NET/C++ library out there that can be reused?

Comment: It's the same idea as in Spy++, too, right?

Comment: As well as the info tool from AutoIt.  It's funny how similar these tools look.  I almost wonder if there's some code being shared around for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Win32 API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32)

- [**GetCursorPos**](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetCursorPos.html): to get the cursor position (maybe .NET has its own function to do that)
- [**WindowFromPoint**](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/WindowFromPoint.html): to get the handle of the window from a specific point in the screen

[more info](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shrijeetnair/win32api12062005005528AM/win32api.aspx)

Comment: That's all there is to it; I wonder why this hasn't been accepted yet.